# Semi-stable equilibria - Real Life Examples?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Hello Mathematics Enthusiasts,

While teaching a course in elementary DE's, I introduced equilibrium and stability.  Of course, we looked at the logistic growth model and saw (both with the slope field and a stability diagram) the stable and unstable equilibria.

Then, just to complete the discussion, I showed them a (contrived) DE that has a semi-stable equilibrium.  A student asked for a practical, i.e. real-life, example.  I was at a loss!!!

Can anyone furnish such an example?

Many TIA!

Abe M.

Comment: If you bump up a dimension, saddles are common in dynamics for coupled system and somewhat generalize a semi-stable equilibrium (have both stable and unstable manifolds).

Comment: Alternatively, something like a rigid pendulum with a motor providing constant torque, Under the the right collection of parameters, the torque and gravitational force can cancel out and the motor holds the pendulum at a fixed angle. If that angle happened to be $\pi/2$ w.r.t. vertical, then giving the pendulum a slight nudge to help the motor along will cause the pendulum to complete another full circuit.

Comment: Why bother with a motor. Put a book on a table, half-hanging over the edge.